# Replacement for "vpn.connectivity" Broadcast Events

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, vpn

I have a problem where I would like to monitor the state of the VPN connection in Android.  I saw that pre-ICS I could set up a broadcast receiver on "vpn.connectivity" actions, but I don't see any analog in ICS or above.

Currently my best option appears to be polling a server that is known to be only accessible through VPN, but polling isn't a good solution for many reasons.  Does anyone have a solution for detecting connect/disconnect events from the built-in VPN client in Android > 4.0?  This seems like a feature that would have been included as a ConnectivityManager broadcast.

I have verified that a BroadcastReceiver listening for "vpn.connectivity" Intents works for an Acer running 3.2, but does not work for a Nexus 7 2013 running 4.4.

**UPDATE:**

I see that there's a VpnService class in ICS.  From my reading of the documentation, it appears that this is for creating a VPN from within your application.  I don't want to have to maintain a VPN client if the one in the system is sufficient.  I would probably accept using this type of a class as a pass-through to a VPN that is configured in the system, but my gut tells me that this isn't possible, given that it seems the OS has locked down visibility into the system VPN configuration and events.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works for Android 5.0+ using its new API.

```
val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN)
        .build()
connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, yourListener)
```